# Working with a Buffer Overflow in a disassembled program

Tags: c, stack, buffer-overflow

So, I was doing a CTF that is now over but was wondering about this one problem.
Once you got past the "log in" page it takes you to this block of code and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to call the function at Address (print flag): 004011e9 by just using this function.

I see that it switches over to a `gets()` call but could not figure out how to abuse it.

Enlighten me!

```
void FUN_00401350(void)
{
    size_t sVar1;
    char Input1[16];
  
    puts("Jarvis: Hello! How can I assist you today?");
    printf("User: ");
    fgets(Input1, 0x10, stdin);
    sVar1 = strcspn(Input1, "\n");
    Input1[sVar1] = '\0';
    getchar();
    puts("Jarvis: Interesting! What else would you like to know?");
    printf("User: ");
    fgets(Input1, 0x10, stdin);
    sVar1 = strcspn(Input1, "\n");
    Input1[sVar1] = '\0';
    getchar();
    puts("Jarvis: Alright, I\'m ready to help. What\'s your query?");
    printf("User: ");
    gets(Input1);
    puts("Jarvis: Sorry, I\'m unable to process your request at the moment.");
    return;
}
```

I tried pushing the buffer out of the way when those `\0` get put in in place of the new line but that led to nothing. Honestly, I just cannot figure this out.

Comment: Is there a question here?  There's a `gets` call with a fixed (16 byte) buffer, so if you give it any input longer that 16 characters (including then newline and NUL), it will overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Since `gets(Input1)` cannot prevent a buffer overflow, the trick is to enter a string that is too long and will overwrite the return address of the function call with appropriate bytes to form the address where you want to jump.  You are instructed to generate a call to the address `004011e9`, so you should coin an input file with an overlong last line ending with the 3 bytes `E9 11 40`, with or without a trailing newline.

Depending on the code generated for this program, the offending line may need to have a length of 19, 23 or 27 bytes.

Of course this only works with a 32-bit compiler and a CPU where the return address is stored on the stack, such as the i386 architecture. ARM CPUs store the return address in a register so this attack would require extra work.